# Jenkins ERROR 403 No valid crumb was included in the request - using github authentication

Tags: c#, security, jenkins, github, http-status-code-403

Recently I upgraded from a very old jenkins version from 2016 to 2.289.1.  I updated all the plugins as well.  Previously we had it setup with github security.  When we would send jobs, it would be sent with the username and oauth key generated from github, and that's how we would track who sent jobs.

After upgrading, every time I would try to send a job I would get HTTP ERROR 403 No valid crumb was included in the request.  I've tried a lot of different solutions I found online, like checking Enable proxy compatibility under crsf protection, or downloading the crumb plugin.  I even started requesting the crumb and attaching it to the header.  In all cases I was still getting the crumb error.

Now if I disabled the github authentication and changed it to jenkins own user database, and replaced the username and token with a jenkins one (and kept the code to insert the crumb into the header) then the job would successfully get sent to jenkins.  I would rather do it through github since that is how we have it setup, anyone have any suggestions now how to get around the crumb error?

here is just a piece of the code that sends the request

```
HttpWebRequest crumbRequest = WebRequest.Create(jenkinsCrumbUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
crumbRequest.Method = "GET";
HttpWebResponse crumbResponse = (HttpWebResponse)crumbRequest.GetResponse();
StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(crumbResponse.GetResponseStream());
string responseString = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
var crumb = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(responseString);

HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(postUrl) as HttpWebRequest;

request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = contentType;
request.UserAgent = userName;
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
request.ContentLength = formData.Length;
request.PreAuthenticate = true;

byte[] credentialBuffer = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(String.Format("{0}:{1}", userName, APIToken));
request.Headers["Authorization"] = String.Format("Basic {0}", Convert.ToBase64String(credentialBuffer));
request.Headers[crumb["crumbRequestField"]] = crumb["crumb"];

using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    requestStream.Write(formData, 0, formData.Length);
    requestStream.Close();
}
return request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

Comment: I think the server is expecting a HTTPS (secure) and you are only sending HTTP.  Change the URI and see what happens.

Comment: Well i discovered if i generate a jenkins token for the account in jenkins that is linked to github one, and use the jenkins token instead of the github Oauth token it ends up working and I do not get the 403 error.  Github authentication still turned on, and is still tracking who sent up the job, so if this works I guess Ill just do it this way.